# How can I do a navigation-drawer with frosted glass effect in vuetify?

Tags: css, vuejs2, vuetify.js, uiblureffect, v-navigation-drawer

I would like to achieve the effect of the deepin operating system control bar. I have dealt with some css codes that I have found online but none works for me on the drawer, if it works on v-cards but not on navigation-drawer.

this is example code

```
<v-app>
    <v-content class="bg">
      <v-container>
        <!-- -->
        <v-app-bar app color="deep-purple accent-4" dark>
          <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>

          <v-toolbar-title>Page title</v-toolbar-title>

          <v-spacer></v-spacer>

          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
          </v-btn>

          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
          </v-btn>

          <v-menu left bottom>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-btn icon v-on="on">
            <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </template>

            <v-list>
              <v-list-item v-for="n in 5" :key="n" @click="() => {}">
                <v-list-item-title>Option {{ n }}</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
          </v-menu>
        </v-app-bar>
        <!-- theme setting -->
        <v-btn small fab dark falt fixed top="top" right="right" class=" elevation-0 setting-fab" color="grey" @click="drawer = !drawer">
          <v-icon>mdi-settings</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        <!-- setting drawer -->

        <v-navigation-drawer temporary v-model="drawer" hide-overlay fixed right width="400px">

          <v-row class="fill-height" no-gutters>
            <!-- Here I load the components dynamically, but to make it simple I will only introduce a v-card into the drawer -->
            <!--         <component v-if="!isSettingOpen" :is="componentToLoad"/> -->

            <v-flex>
              <v-card class="ma-auto FBox-root FBox-acrylic FCard-root" color="#385F73" dark style="position: relative">
                <v-card-title class="headline">Unlimited music now</v-card-title>

                <v-card-subtitle>Listen to your favorite artists and albums whenever and wherever, online and offline.</v-card-subtitle>

                <v-card-actions>
                  <v-btn text>Listen Now</v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
              </v-card>
            </v-flex>
          </v-row>
        </v-navigation-drawer>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
```

This is the css

```
.setting-fab {
        top: 30% !important;
        right: 0;
        border-radius: 20%;
    }

   .bg {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1920/1080?random) center center / cover
    fixed;
}

.FBox-acrylic::after {
  inset: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: "";
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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");
}

.FCard-acrylic::before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  transition: box-shadow 250ms cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.1, 0.33, 1) 0ms,
    filter 250ms cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.1, 0.33, 1) 0ms;
}

.FBox-acrylic::before {
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  filter: blur(10px);
  height: calc(100% + 20px);
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  background: inherit;
}

.FCard-root {
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 3.2px 7.2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.132),
    0px 0.6px 1.8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.108);
  transition: box-shadow 250ms cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.1, 0.33, 1) 0ms,
    filter 250ms cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.1, 0.33, 1) 0ms;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.FBox-acrylic {
  z-index: 1;
  background: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v-card::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/100/100) center center / cover
    fixed;
  filter: blur(3px)
}

.v-navigation-drawer::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background: grey
}
.v-navigation-drawer {
  background: transparent !important
}
```

The sample code is in the following link [Example Code](https://codepen.io/yuniel-acosta/pen/WNbxEPW)

The idea is to achieve the effect of blurring everything that lies behind the drawer. The photos show the effect that I wish to achieve
[Example of the effect of the deepin operating system control bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmHi0.jpg)

I hope you can help me. Cheers

Comment: Adding a div over the part you want to blur and use the ::after css event to show it or so?

Comment: I don't understand. Add div in the part I want to blur and applied FBox-acrylic::after. Could you modify https://codepen.io/yuniel-acosta/pen/WNbxEPW because I don't understand